# Android studio: build sqlite select query dynamically depending on values in json array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, where-clause

I'm working in Android studio (java).
I'm working with a sqlite database and I want to be able to query a table. I would currently use the following code:
''

```
                    String strQuery = "select * from table where var1 = ?";

                    SQLiteStatement stmt = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(strQuery);
                    stmt.bindString(1, String.valueOf(strVarOne));
                    stmt.execute();
```

''

But I need to dynamically build the WHERE statement. I currently have a json array which I want to use to build the where statement that looks like this (for example).

```
[{"country":"South Africa"},{"province":"Gauteng"}]
```

In the above example I would want the query to look as follows:

```
"select * from table where country = 'South Africa' and province= 'Gauteng' "
```

Can anyone assist with how I could build and run that query dynamically depending on the json array?
Bear in mind that the json array may change - the values may differ and there may be more of them.

Comment: What is your database table structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Place {
     @SerializedName("country")
     String country = null;
     @SerializedName("province")
     String province = null;
}

Type token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Place>>(){}.type
String yourJson = "[{\"country":\"South Africa\"},{\"province\":\"Gauteng\"}]";
Gson gson = new Gson();

ArrayList<Place> places = gson.fromJson(yourJson, token);

String selectFormat = "select * from table where %$1s = '%$2s' and %$3s = '%$4s' "

ArrayList<String> selectArguments = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<places.size(); i++){
  if(places.country!=null){
     selectArguments.add("country");
     selectArguments.add(places.country);
  }else if(places.province != null) {
    selectArguments.add("province");
     selectArguments.add(places.province);
  }
}
```

I will not go as far as to tell you how to avoid SQL injection.

```
String fullSQLStatement = String.format(selectFormat,selectArguments.toArray(new String[selectArguments.size()]);
```

`fullSQLStatement` would become `select * from table where country = 'South Africa' and province = 'Gauteng'`